# Will Locust master accept and utilize additional slaves after —expect-slaves number is met?

Tags: python, locust

If I’m running a Locust master headless with —expect-slaves 3, if I connect 5 slaves will the master accept and utilize all connected slaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. If the --expect-slave 3 is passed, the master will wait for 3 slaves to start the testing, but it can accept 5 slaves. Below is the content from the official documentation website.

```
--expect-slaves=X
  Used when starting the master node with --no-web. The master node will then wait until X slave nodes has  connected before the test is started.
```

Link: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html#options